# Bootstrap dropdown menu just not working on root/home page

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a boostrap drop down menu on my nav bar. It is working fine on on all pages, except the home page. I believe it has to do with the application.js file, so does the order before or after jquery.ujs matter? How come the menu just won't drop down on the root/home page?

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require jquery.masonry.min.js
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

view the source of home page , and check the javascript files `jquery.js` and `bootstrap.js` loaded correctly. use firebug and check the js console

#### Here is a the screen short of google chrome console window.

[image: google chrome console]

the errors are shown in red color.

Comment: Got it Suhail, much appreciated for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Adding this code at the bottem of the application.js did the trick.

$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()